# Multiple levels of horizontal / vertical "stack panels" in HTML

Tags: css, layout, html

I have the need to render arbitrary bits of content (form elements, text, images) in HTML.  Layout-wise, the concept of a "stack panel" from XAML is close to what I'm looking for.  Some of the content I want to lay out vertically, and some horizontally.  So, I want the HTML to look something like this:

```
<div class="stack-vert">
    <div class="stack-vert">
        <div class="content">Vert 1</div>
        <div class="content">Vert 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack-horz">
        <div class="content" style="width: 50px; height: 75px;">Horz 1</div>
        <div class="content" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;">Horz 2</div>
        <div class="content" style="width: 100px; height: 200px;">Horz 3</div>
        <div class="stack-vert">
            <div class="content">Horz 4, Vert 1</div>
            <div class="content">Horz 4, Vert 2</div>
        </div>
    </div>          
    <div class="stack-vert">
        <div class="content">Vert 3</div>
        <div class="content">Vert 4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The hard coded widths and heights are just there to simulate content of different sizes.  I have CSS that correctly lays out one level of horizontal, vertical correctly:

```
DIV.stack-vert
{
    border: solid thick red;
}

DIV.stack-horz
{
    border: solid thick blue;
}

DIV.content
{
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: grey;
    margin: 5px;

}

DIV.stack-horz DIV.content
{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

This HTML and CSS renders like this:

[image]

As you can see, what I'm hoping to achieve is that "Horz 4, Vert 1" and "Horz 4, Vert 2" render to the right of "Horz 3", but in a vertical stack.  However, this is not happening, because the stack-vert display of block.

How do I achieve "stack panel" like layout of arbitrary content sections using HTML / CSS, and to an arbitrary depth of containers?

NOTE: Ideally I'd like to solve this using "raw" HTML / CSS but I would consider framework-based solutions such as with jQuery.

EDIT #1: @Aequanox's answer is close, but it doesn't support IE 9.  IE 9 support is essential, as most of my users are on that browser (it's an internal app).

Comment: As for a jQuery solution, Masonry is quite powerful: http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: It doesn't look like Masonry supports the idea of having layout "panels" within other panels, which is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could change the CSS in this way

```
DIV.stack-vert
{
    border: solid thick red;
    overflow:hidden;
}

DIV.stack-horz
{
    border: solid thick blue;
    overflow:hidden;
}

DIV.content
{
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: grey;
    margin: 5px;

}

DIV.stack-horz > DIV.content
{
    float:left;
}
```

See an example here : http://jsfiddle.net/3e6AY/

Comment: That seems to do the trick, although I had to change the last selector to DIV.stack-horz > DIV.content in order to allow for arbitrary depth rendering correctly.  Thanks!

Comment: OK, not quite.  1) this doesn't work in IE 9.  What is the trick to get that working?  2) Can you explain what the overflow:hidden is doing?  It seems essential to get it to render right, but I'm not sure *why* it is working, which always makes me uneasy.

Comment: The overflow:hidden is used to trick the browser in giving the float element a block-formatting context, thus rendering itself with a proper box size.

Comment: Mmmh, that's strange... It's working for me, are you sure you're not on "Quirks Mode" ?

Comment: Yeah it was a quirks mode issue.  Add <!DOCTYPE HTML> fixed it.  Working now!

Comment: It should work in IE7 (your definition of "should" may vary because, well, IE ^^ but the instructions should work and direct child selector is IE7+)